# Is it possible to instantiate a Map with a list of keys?

Tags: java, dictionary

Usually, if I know beforehand all the keys of a map, I instantiate it like this:

```
    List<String> someKeyList = getSomeList();
    Map<String, Object> someMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(someKeyList.size());

    for (String key : someKeyList) {
        someMap.put(key, null);
    }
```

Is there any way to do this directly without needing to iterate through the list? Something to the effect of:

```
new HashMap<String, Object>(someKeyList)
```

My first thought was to edit the map's keyset directly, but the operation is not supported. Is there other way I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Java 8 Streams :

```
Map<String,Object> someMap = 
    someKeyList.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k,k->null));
```

Note that if you want a specific `Map` implementation, you'll have to use a different `toMap` method, in which you can specify it.

Comment: What should we do when we are using earlier version of **Java 8**?

Comment: @mmuzahid The OP can use the code that appears in the question if they can't use Java 8.

Comment: Thank you! Just the one-liner I needed :)